# Issue with Axios onUploadProgress event Not Triggering on Capacitor Android

Tags: ionic-framework, axios, capacitor

I'm currently facing an issue with Axios where the `onUploadProgress` event doesn't seem to be triggered during file uploads. I've reviewed the Axios documentation and implemented the necessary configurations, but I'm not getting the expected progress updates.

The file(s) gets uploaded successfully and these no console error/warning

> Although it works and shows the upload event on their web preview!

```js
axios.post('upload-url', form, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
  },

  onUploadProgress: progressEvent => {
    console.log('here', progressEvent); // NOT reached
  },
})
.then(response => {
  console.log('Upload complete:', response.data);
})
.catch(error => {
  console.error('Upload failed:', error);
});
```

**P.S: I'm using Axios & Capacitor latest version as for now**

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions from the community on why the event might not be triggering in my Axios implementation. If anyone has faced a similar issue or has recommendations on debugging this, please share your thoughts.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!